# Installation of Linux mint from cd makes it stuck on splash screen.

Tags: linux, system-installation, bootsplash

I am installing Linux mint Rebecca cinnamon onto a Windows XP Professional computer. I burned the ISO file using windows burner (Windows XP Professional)

The menu loads correctly.

Let it boot automatically. The splash screen is there and frozen
On pressing arrow keys, text appears. 
[image: Message]
[image: Message]

2. Do integrity check. 
   *Error in 8 files.*
   However I checked the md5 sum already, I know the file is proper. 
   [image: Message]
   ***what should I do?.***

Comment: Have you verified the checksum of the disc? You might have errors on the ISO.

Comment: How do you verify the checksum of the disk???    I checked the checksum of the file before burning.

Comment: Normally there is a hash (`md5sum`, `SHA1` etc) on the page where you download the ISO. You compare that with the one generated on the downloaded file and/or the ISO you burned (for that you need to install the corresponding program on WinXP, or do this on another Linux machine you might have access to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iso you download may be correct md5 wise, but the problem may be either with the way the DVD is recorded or the way it is read by the drive.

You can try burning the iso with an other program, like Infrarecorder (http://infrarecorder.org/) and verify the image when burning it, or you may try making a bootable usb flash and boot from that.

Comment: My computer won't recognise USB as a bootable device (I've tried everything.

Comment: When I download infrarecorder from sourceforge, chrome says it is malicious. Are you sure it is good. Could you suggest a better download site.

Comment: There is a link on their download page to download it from Fosshub, Chome will not block it.

If booting from usb is not an option, you might have to replace your notebook drive